# Small size transformer - Design or Pre-made

Tags: power-supply, avr, transformer

I am wondering how to acquire or design a small transformer. In my circuit, I need to add a transformer mainly to power my AVR and a bluetooth module. I would like it to be as small as possible as I plan to add the whole thing in a small enclosure.

I recently saw this Belkin Plug [here](http://www.belkin.com/uk/Products/home-automation/c/wemo-home-automation/) and I am wondering how do they do it? Can these transformers be bought off the shelf or easily ordered.

The other option would be to power with a coin cell but I rather no go down that route

Comment: Look up offline power supplies.

Comment: Numbers, please. "As small as possible" is not a spec. What incoming voltage and what output voltage, at what current is required?

Answer (score 1):

Most applications these days no longer rely on conventional transformers, instead they use a "switching mode power supply" or short SMPS. This technique is used in for instance modern cell phone chargers.

The main advantage of SMPS is that these require a much smaller footprint that a bulky transformer.

If you like to design such a power supply have a look at the design tool from NXP: http://nxp.transim.com/fb/design.aspx it gives most of the information and circuitry needed to design your own. The tool also gives instructions on how to wind the transformer coils yourself. If you don't want to wind the transformer yourself, you can buy one off the shelf or have one custom made.